# Is there something comparable or similar to the Xcode clang static analyzer for Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, xcode

I realize Objective-C and Java are two completely different beasts, but I was wondering if there were any code optimization and memory tools comparable to Xcode's clang static analyzer?

I'm looking for a quick way to track down some bugs, specifically potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Android has their own set of tools you can use. Take a look here at the full list of available tools

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html

for specifically looking at memory issues you can use the Memory Analyzer tool

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html